# how to disable my toggle button? This is my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label class="switch switch-yes-no" id="check_'+id+'" style="margin: 0;font-weight: bold;">
<input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" id="check_'+id+'" />
<span class="switch-label" data-on="Published" data-off="Hidden">  </span> 
<span class="switch-handle"></span>
</label>
```

I want to disable my input button.

Comment: `$('.switch-input').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: I have tried this so many times but it isn't working..

Comment: $('.switch-input').attr('disabled', 'disabled')

Comment: Check my answer, it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the button by default then

```
<input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" id="check_'+id+'" disabled/>
```

If you want to disable button on some action in jquery

```
$(function(){
   $('#SomeButton').on('click', function(){
        $('#your_input_id').attr('disabled' , 'disabled') //OR
        $('#your_input_id').prop('disabled' , true) //true for disabled, false to enable
   });
});
```

Or, if you want to disabled by default on page load WITHOUT any action

```
$(function(){
        $('#your_input_id').attr('disabled' , 'disabled') //OR
        $('#your_input_id').prop('disabled' , true) //true for disabled, false to enable
});
```

Comment: Actually when my code executes the button is disabled by default but I want to make it enable on some action

Comment: I have tried .prop('disabled' , true) previously but it isn't working

Comment: do `.prop('disabled' , false)` to enable your already disabled button/checkbox, use `true` to disable